# Disadvantage of Python eggs?

Tags: python, comparison, egg

Are there any disadvantages about using eggs through `easy-install` compared to the "traditional" packages/modules/libs?

Comment: @Ian Bicking should have something to say on this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One (potential) disadvantage is that eggs are zipped by default unless `zip_safe=False` is set in their `setup()` function in `setup.py`. If an egg is zipped, you can't get at the files in it (without unzipping it, obviously). If the module itself uses non-source files (such as templates) it will probably specify `zip_safe=False`, but another consequence is that you cannot effectively step into zipped modules using `pdb`, the Python debugger. That is, you can, but you won't be able to see the source or navigate properly.

Comment: You could always use `easy_install -Z` to force it to install unzipped.  There's also a way to configure it to unzip by default.

Comment: I got the Mercurial egg, but TortoiseHg didn't recognize it, so i had to install it the traditional way. Does it  have anything to do with the zip thing?

Comment: @Daniel: "There's also a way to configure it to unzip by default" how?

Answer (score 8):

Using eggs does cause a long `sys.path`, which has to be searched and when it's *really* long that search can take a while.  Only when you get a hundred entries or so is this going to be a problem (but installing a hundred eggs via easy_install is certainly possible).